# List to data frame conversion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list with 7 elements each containing array of 4209 elements as below :

d=[array([32, 32, 20, ...,  8,  9, 46]), array([23, 21, 24, ..., 23, 19, 19]), array([17, 19, 34, ..., 38, 25,  3]), array([0, 4, 2, ..., 0, 5, 2]), array([24, 28, 27, ...,  0,  0,  0]), array([ 9, 11,  9, ...,  6, 11,  6]), array([14, 14, 23, ...,  4, 20, 22])]
How do I create Dataframe using each list element as index ie. x0 x1 ...x6?

I tried converting in array using np.array(d) and then reshaping with 7 cols,it gives wrong values

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you need:

```
d = [np.random.randint(0, 100, 4209) for i in range(7)]

print(d)

[array([89, 60,  0, ..., 13, 74, 39]),
 array([74,  4, 18, ..., 45, 29, 96]),
 array([66, 17, 66, ..., 98, 60,  0]),
 array([28, 90, 99, ..., 15, 11, 44]),
 array([ 6, 49, 66, ..., 88, 19, 95]),
 array([22, 93, 29, ..., 56, 57, 34]),
 array([75, 41, 18, ..., 99, 84,  6])]

df = pd.DataFrame(d).T

print(df)

       0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0     89  74  66  28   6  22  75
1     60   4  17  90  49  93  41
2      0  18  66  99  66  29  18
3     52  50  20  84  53  31  23
4     20  83  19  91  84   5  41
...   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
4204  29  22  71  35  92  50  11
4205  56  30  33  83  39  11  14
4206  13  45  98  15  88  56  99
4207  74  29  60  11  19  57  84
4208  39  96   0  44  95  34   6
```

Comment: Wow ..it actually worked..just i have to rename columns ..thnkx